# How can I match repeating pattern in this string?

Tags: regex, pcre

I am trying to find the matches of the contains query in the following ODATA filter:

```
Name eq 'test' and contains(Address,'fdgr345') and contains(Description,'test')
```

I am using the regex:
`(contains\s*\(([\w]+)\,\'([\s\w\s]+\')\))+`.

However, this regex returns only the first match i.e.
`contains(Address,'fdgr345')`.

How can I get all the occurrences of the `contains(..., '...')` pattern?

Comment: Probalbly using the good method or function. Is it PHP? is it C#?

Comment: You are welcome but you need to be more specific in particular for the language you use.

Comment: Edited the tags. I am using PCRE

Comment: This is something that must be done outside the Regex engine (unless you want to concat all matches to a single string). E.g. if using PHP, replace `preg_match` with `preg_match_all`. Any Regex API in any language or library should have this functionality in one form or another.

Comment: Not only does PCRE not give us enough info, you are not providing the PCRE version being used, so we don't even know what feature/functionality limitations you have, regardless of language. I'm not trying to knock you down, just some important info! :) And I'm fairly fond of last year's release...

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass some form of global flag in order to tell regex to capture all instances of your regex.

Typically this can look something like this:

```
/REGEX/flags
```

or in your case:

```
/contains\s*\(([\w]+)\,\'([\s\w\s]+\')\)/g
```

where the g-flag denotes global. Additionally I removed the outer ()+ since this is trying to match repeated patterns like so:

```
TEXTnStuff contains(Address,'fdgr345')contains(Address,'abc123') MORETEXT
```